# command line find multiple strings

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I'm trying to find multiple strings via a single command.  All of the examples of the windows find command that I'm finding are for a single string. How would I pass a list?

**Works**

```
pip list -format=legacy | find "acqusition"
```

**Does not work**

```
pip list -format=legacy | find "acqusition|apidev-coop"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the findstr command instead.

```
pip list | findstr -i "astroid apidev-coop"
```

You can then search for a space delimited list of strings.